# Is it possible for real time access to mobile device camera?

Tags: javascript, mobile

So I'm wondering if it's possible for a website to be able A) access the mobile device's camera and B) have real time facial recognition capabilities? Essentially what Snapchat does, albeit much simpler, but in a web application opposed to a mobile application?

I already know the answer to (A), as found here: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/iphone-camera.php

And I even found an example that uses Amazon Rekognition, as found here: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-face-recognition-web-app-in-under-an-hour-345aa91487c

Only nuisance with the rekognition example I found was that it seems to take the picture **AND THEN** do the recognition, I'm looking more for something to do it while the camera is up (so you point the camera to someones face, and it does the magic there).

**Disclaimer**: I am not asking anyone to do any work for me here. I know I'm not providing any code samples, and that's because I'm just in the research phase and wanted to see if anyone here has any input on what I'm trying to achieve.

Something tells me this may not be possible, from my google searches I didn't quite find anything that I'm looking for, but close.

Comment: I would take a look at phoneGap. I think with that you can access to camera.

Comment: The point is not have to build an app and have to publish it on the store.

Comment: Also, I know how to have access to camera anyways already via web site on a mobile phone. The idea is to be able to interact with what's in the camera, and do real time recognition.

Comment: you don't need to build an app for that. you can use phoneGap in web interface as well.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: It is basically a javascript library to build web apps using javascript and html. So I am not sure how it will react if you open that page on a desktop computer but mobile browser should react properly.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlBfmHDZjmg

Comment: Yes I've used Cordova before to build a mobile app, never tried to use it in a web browser. However, I guess it should work considering it goes into a web view anyways.